# How can I save a photo of part of the screen to the local iPhone's Photos?

Tags: iphone

I have put a UILabel that the user has chosen over a UIImageView that was also chosen by the user. I would like to put these two into a picture, kind of like a screenshot of a small part of the screen. I have absolutely no idea how to do this and have no experience in this. Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a Bitmap context with a clipping mask of the area you want to save. Then you use the backing layer's renderInContext method to draw onto that context.

```
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(960, 580); 

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(10,10,200,200); // whatever rect you want

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Save to camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, self, @selector(didSaveImage), null);
```