# Can not save a part of the screen in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to take a screenshot of a part of the iphone screen, but I don't know why I'm stuck. I don't know what I am doing wrong,  because i get no errors on th execution. I have see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132014/how-can-i-save-a-photo-of-part-of-the-screen-to-the-local-iphones-photos) here, and follow step by step, but... I do not wheres is the error... so please help guys

here is my code:

```
-(void)saveImageBig
{
    UIImage *myBigImage = [self imageFromBig]; // this method returns a UIImage to store inside myBigImage

    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; //the directory

    NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myPic.png",docDir]; // the full path of the image .PNG
    NSLog(@"%@", pngFilePath); //just to check the address
    NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(myBigImage)]; //Create an NSData from the PNG
    [data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES]; //Put the data inside the address as a PNG
}

-(UIImage *)imageFromBig
{
    CGSize size  = CGSizeMake(568.0, 288.0); //a part of the iphone screen
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0.0); 
    UIImage *bigImage; //The image pointer
    UIImageView *bigImageView;

    [bigImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(16, 20, size.width, size.height)];  //Beginning X16 Y20 take a screenshot of 568X288 (size)
    bigImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(bigImage, self,@selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    return bigImage; //Save the image into albumns
}

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{ //just the alerts... 
    if (error != NULL)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Image could not be saved.Please try again"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Close", nil];
        [alert show]; //Not saved
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Image was successfully saved in photoalbum"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Close", nil];
        [alert show]; //Saved
    }
}

- (IBAction)SaveImageBtn:(id)sender
{
    [self saveImageBig];
}
```

The result says that the image was successfully saved, but the image es blank, empty but there is objects and cotrols in that area (size = 568X288).

Hope you can help me with this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying this:

```
UIImageView *bigImageView;
[bigImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(16, 20, size.width, size.height)];
```

So in the first line you *declare* a UIImageView. You do not initialize it, so it is nil. In the second line you obtain the `image` of this nil image view, which is nil. And then you draw nil into your graphics context - which, as you say, is therefore blank.

It is far from clear what *you* expect to accomplish with this nonsense, but you are getting exactly what *I* would expect you to get, namely, nothing. What you imagine any of that has to do with "save a part of the screen" beats the heck out of me. None of your code has *anything* to do with anything on the screen.

Comment: I'm fixing my questions to be more clear. And your answer is point to the right answer.